# Combining body building and grappling

Tags: bodybuilding

I am training to build body mass.

Does a grappling session once a week, which lasts for 2 hours, will effect my muscle size or performance at the gym.

I want to do the session on a day that I dont work out.

Comment: My guess is that grappling is going to be somewhat counter productive if your true goal is to "build body mass" ("size"), mainly because it is a very, very intense cardio workout. However, grappling will aid tremendously in building your core strength.

Comment: If you wanted to be a competitive grappler who was also a competitive bodybuilder, you could have a challenge on your hands...but for 2 hours/week--no, it won't affect your gains significantly, at least not in anyway that couldn't be easily made up in a half-thought out nutrition program.   I've rolled with some very jacked individuals who train a heck of a lot longer than two hours/week.  You'll be fine.

Answer (score 2):

I dont recommend grappling if you want to put on some body mass.  Your core strength can be improved and you can tone your body too but grappling will not help you put on body mass.